# Does a transitive action of $O(L^{\#}/L)$ imply a transitive action of $O(L)$ on $L^{\#}/L$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, lattices, orthogonal-groups

Given an even lattice $L$ the orthogonal group $O(L)$ acts on the discriminant group $L^{\#}/L$ as is known. Hence, for every $\gamma \in O(L)$ there is a $\overline{\gamma}\in O(L^{\#}/L)$ that acts on $L^{\#}/L$ the same way.

In my setting I consider indefinite lattices of signature (1,n), $n\geq 2$, which split a hyperbolic plane, i.e. $L= H + L_0$, where $L_0$ let be an even positive definite lattice and $H$ a standard hyperbolic plane.
Additionally, let $L$ be maximal. And you may assume that the lattice is over $\mathbb{Z}$.
If $O(L)$ acts transitively on elements $L^{\#}/L$ of the same norm, then $O(L^{\#}/L)$ does so too.

My question now is: Is the reverse true?
So, if $O(L^{\#}/L)$ acts transitively on the elements with the same norm, does $O(L)$ act transitively?
Which additional assumptions are needed? Or is this not possible in general?